# Can we make a obejct in request scope which is defined defined a session scoped object?

Tags: java, session, request

I  have class A and Class B defined. And I am using the Class B object in Class A.

Here I am going to add the class A object in session scope. I am aware as B object is defined in the A it is by default available in session scope. But I want B object should be recreated or reset the values on every single request. is that possible define a object in request scope inside a session scoped object?

Thanks,
Naren

Answer (score 0):

You can insert object of any scope in session scope.
The only thing is the value from some scope will always be present till session terminates.
Even if you want to update the object in request scope present in session scope ,it can be updated on every request.You need to access the object from session scope on each request and update it and then use it wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. Just want to know how can we achieve that in java coding.

Comment: Check this link:http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting.This will be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, but you have to be careful when assigning the field. In other words, you should not use `new B()`, but rely on the dependency injection capabilities of your framework to bind the field for you. Pseudocode:

```
@Scoped("session")
public class SessionBean {
  @Injected
  private RequestBean requestBean;
}

@Scoped("request")
public class RequestBean {}
```

The exact implementation of course depends on the DI framework used.